# Is there a way to get point position of char?

Tags: computational-geometry

From basic math I know how to get a point from a circle:

```
x = (int) (xCenter + radius * Math.cos(angle));
y = (int) (yCenter + radius * Math.sin(angle));
```

[image]

So changing variable `angle` I can get any point of a circle, or draw a circle if I continiously inrement `angle` from `0` to `2PI`.

Is there a way to get a point position from complex objects like Letters, where I  can get any point of shapre representing Character or draw it on continious incremention ?
[image]

Comment: No idea what you mean by this.

Comment: Are you asking, "Is there a formula for the letter p that I can use to plot the points of the letter?"  If that's your question, the answer is "No."

Comment: @DavidHoelzer there is formula to draw batman sign http://paulhastings.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/wpid-facebook_-188174178.jpg I hope there is also formula to draw letter `p` or `g` or other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of "a letter" depends on the font, obviously. I believe most vector fonts (like PostScript and TrueType) are just Bézier curves, which are purely mathematical, so you may be able to derive a formula or algorithm by studying Bézier curves.

Some resources to get you started:

- [Wikipedia: Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (with lots of juicy formulas!)
- [PostScript and Geometry](http://merganser.math.gvsu.edu/david/psseminar/) by David Austin in GVSU's Math department
- [Guide to PostScript Programming](http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/postscript.html) by Peter Weingartner
- [PostScript](http://odur.let.rug.nl/~kleiweg/postscript/postscript.html) by Peter Kleiweg